# Design Pattern: Active Record Performance and Flexibility

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am about to develop a new application and am considering the best practices

I have read about ActiveRecords and I have used it before but I always want something that would make changes easier and less time consuming.

**Using active record and other ORMs**:
I believe that these methods loads all records from the database when sometimes I may need just one or two

Like if I want to do paging, i need to pass the pageIndex and pageSize, how would you do that without loading all the data

Like if i want multiple fields in my WHERE clause
Wouldn't I load all records and filter based on my criteria

I would like all the selection/filtering/sorting to happen at the database level

Adding static methods to perform those operations look like I would be doing the wrong thing

Are there ORMs that handle that gracefully?

I want to have utmost control over the application flow so I can easily optimize when necessary.

Note: I am still researching on **DAO and other methods** but I want opinions on Active Record in case I still want to use it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# 3.5+, I believe `Linq`, `IQueryable` and proper Data Service Layer can solve your problem.

1. Paging. IQueryable is by default, not commit until you call toList(). You can have your Data Store return IQueryable with **ALL** items, but do the filtering and paging at last, and only the items you needed is processed,

e.g.

```
var items = getAllItems(); // IQueyrable<Item>, from database

var paged = items.Skip(50).Take(10); // Database still not queried
paged.toList(); // Database return 10 items only
```

1. Filtering and WHERE. Same as above
2. Most ORM works with Linq. E.g. NHibernate
3. > utmost control over the application flow .

   Probably you need to write your own custom Linq Providers, but trust me, you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for that. But my worry is line1 where you have to get all items from the DB. In an environment like web where multiple users are using your application, don't you think loading all data into memory would impact performance? Unless the server is up for it.

Comment: As I mentioned, IQueryable will not load until toList(). In my example above, only that 10 items are loaded. The Linq Provider will translate the above chain of items to something like: select top 10 * from table  skip 50; (sorry I'm poor in SQL syntax)